# Unique grouping and count situation for rolling up to parent groupings

Tags: sql, presto

I am working on working on forming a logic:

| user_id | city | county | state | country | region | is_perm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Oakland | Alameda | California | United States | North America | True |
| First | Fremont | Alameda | California | United States | North America | False |
| First | Broolyn | Kings | New York | United States | North America | True |
| Second | San Francisco | San Francisco | California | United States | North America | True |
| Second | Cleveland | Cuyahoga | Ohio | United States | North America | False |

I am looking for output of following:

| user_id | unique_city_count | unique_county_count | unique_state_count | unique_country | unique_region | perm_unique_city_count | perm_unique_county_count | perm_unique_state_count | perm_unique_country | perm_unique_region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| Second | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

**Column definitions:**

- user_id: User ID
- unique_city_count: Unique City Counts
- unique_county_count: Unique County Counts
- unique_state_count: Unique State Counts
- unique_country: Unique Country Counts
- unique_region: Unique Region Counts
- perm_unique_city_count: Unique City Counts who has a permanent home
- perm_unique_county_count: Unique City Counts who has a permanent home
- perm_unique_state_count: Unique City Counts who has a permanent home
- perm_unique_country: Unique City Counts who has a permanent home
- perm_unique_region: Unique City Counts who has a permanent home

Could anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what database you're using, but this should work with most relational databases. There's a lot of COALESCE statements here, but those are necessary because one could only have perm (or non-perm) addresses, which could result in NULL values.

```
WITH perm AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT city) perm_unique_city_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT county) perm_unique_county_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT state) perm_unique_state_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT country) perm_unique_country,
        COUNT(DISTINCT region) perm_unique_region
    FROM
        table
    WHERE is_perm=True
    GROUP BY user_id
),
alldata AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT city) unique_city_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT county) unique_county_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT state) unique_state_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT country) unique_country,
        COUNT(DISTINCT region) unique_region
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(perm.user_id,alldata.user_id) user_id,
    COALESCE(alldata.unique_city_count,0) unique_city_count,
    COALESCE(alldata.unique_county_count,0) unique_county_count,
    COALESCE(alldata.unique_state_count,0) unique_state_count,
    COALESCE(alldata.unique_country,0) unique_country,
    COALESCE(alldata.unique_region,0) unique_region,
    COALESCE(perm.perm_unique_city_count,0) perm_unique_city_count,
    COALESCE(perm.perm_unique_county_count,0) perm_unique_county_count,
    COALESCE(perm.perm_unique_state_count,0) perm_unique_state_count,
    COALESCE(perm.perm_unique_country,0) perm_unique_country,
    COALESCE(perm.perm_unique_region,0) perm_unique_region
FROM
    alldata
FULL OUTER JOIN
    perm
ON
    perm.user_id=alldata.user_id
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(perm.user_id,alldata.user_id);
```

Comment: _"You didn't mention what database you're using,"_ - I see question being tagged with Presto.

Comment: Yes, it is for Presto DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options if the is_perm = true runs into error:

- is_perm is true
- is_perm = 'true'

```
select 
user_id,
count(distinct city) as unique_city_count,
count(distinct county) as unique_county_count,
count(distinct country) as unique_country_count,
count(distinct state) as unique_state_count,
count(distinct region) as unique_region_count,
count(distinct (case when is_perm = true then city end)) as perm_unique_city_count,
count(distinct (case when is_perm = true then county end)) as perm_unique_county_count
count(distinct (case when is_perm = true then country end)) perm_unique_country_count,
count(distinct (case when is_perm = true then state end)) as perm_unique_state_count,
count(distinct (case when is_perm = true then region end)) as perm_unique_region_count
from <table_name>
group by 1
```